# Attempting to install Paperclip gem - Could not find paperclip-3.4.2 in any of the sources (sudo vs. no sudo issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, paperclip

I am running Ruby on Rails on a production server. Some how, I believe the version of Ruby on the server is completely messed up.

Although it is not generally a problem, it becomes a large problem when I attempt to install the paperclip gem on the server.

Initially, I add it to the Gemfile and run `bundle install`. Everything completes successfully, but when I attempt to access the website, I receive the following error in the Apache log file:

```
*** Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Could not find paperclip-3.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)) (process *****, thread #<Thread:********>):
```

Needless to say, this is extremely frustrating. When I run `bundle install` again, I receive no errors. However, when I run `sudo bundle install`, everything completes, until I reach paperclip in which I receive an error like so (not actual error, but similar):

```
Paperclip does not support Ruby <= 1.9.2
```

At this point, I was stumped. I ran `ruby -v` and, as I predicted, I received:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (****-**-** revision *****) [i686-linux]
```

By pure chance, I also ran `sudo ruby -v` and was completely surprised to see:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (****-**-** patchlevel ***) [i486-linux]
```

I use RVM to manage Ruby, and only 1.9.2 is installed. When I try to list them using sudo, I recieve an 'RVM not found' error.

Am I correct in assuming that paperclip can't be found in the sources because it is executing as a sudo user and using an older version of Ruby? At this point I'm very confused and would really appreciate any assistance you can offer.

Unfortunately, I cannot wipe the server and start anew. Where should I go to from here? I've scoured the web and haven't found anything like this sudo/no sudo issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `sudo` with rvm, you need to use `rvmsudo`.  So, when installing Passenger, you'd run `rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module.

Not sure what what OS you are using, but here's a guide geared toward setting up Apache/Passenger using RVM on CentOS.